# Прорисовка drawable по клику

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

Я создал свою реализацию ImageView и переопределил метод onDraw(Canvas canvas);
Все работает, но я хочу **чтоб при нажатии на Button, на моем полотне дополнительно появлялся drawable** в указанных координатах, не более.
Т.е у меня уже есть на полотне drawable, при клике button появлялось ещё одно drawable.

## MainActivity.java

## **Не работает**

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
    MyImageView imageView;
    Button btn;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        imageView = (MyImageView) findViewById(R.id.canvas);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
        btn.setOnClickListener(this);

    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Bitmap bitmap = 
BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.bumerang);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap,0,0,null);
        imageView.draw(canvas); //пытаюсь нарисовать на полотне drawable
        imageView.invalidate(); // как гласит легенда update метода onDraw
    }
}
```

## MyImageView.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;


/**
 * Created by AndrewPC on 17.07.2017.
 */

public class MyImageView extends 
android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView {
    private Canvas canvas;
    public MyImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyImageView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MyImageView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.plate);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap,0,0,null); // тут все работает как надо
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Нашел кривое решение, но благо работает.

```
public void update(){ //вызывая этот метод canvas обновляется
    isDraw = true; //разрешает нарисовать drawable
    invalidate(); // вызывает onDraw();
}

public void drawBitmap(){
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.bumerang);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap,0,0,null);
    invalidate();
}
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    this.canvas = canvas;
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    if(isDraw) drawBitmap(); //когда onDraw вызвался, вызывается метод drawBitmap();

}
```

### Есть ли у кого решение без говнокода?

Comment: Так у вас же тут зацикливание. `update` вызывает `invalidate`, который вызывает `onDraw`, который вызывает `drawBitmap`, который вызывает `invalidate` и т.д. ... В целом, вариант решения с флагом вполне нормальный. Только декодирование ресурса нужно вынести из `onDraw`.